# Threshold weak classifier

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, classification, face-detection

I'm trying to build a strong classifier using the AdaBoost Viola & Jones. I know what is a weak classifier but I do not find the way to specify the threshold teta a the the parity p of each weak classifier.
Can any one tell or explain how i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have do some research and i find this M

In the original viola-Jones paper here, section 3.1 Learning Discussion (para 4, to be precise) you will find out the procedure to find optimal threshold.

I'll sum up the method quickly below.

Optimal threshold for each feature is sample-weight dependent and therefore calculated in very iteration of adaboost. The best weak classifier's threshold is saved as mentioned in the pseudo code.

In every round, for each weak classifier, you have to arrange the N training samples according to the feature value. Putting a threshold will separate this sequence in 2 parts. Both parts will have either positive or negative samples in majority along with a few samples of other type.

T+ : total sum of positive sample weights
T- : total sum of negative sample weights
S+ : sum of positive sample weights below the threshold
S- : sum of negative sample weights below the threshold
Error for this particular threshold is -
e = MIN((S+) + (T-) - (S-), (S-) + (T+) - (S+))
You calculate this error for all N possible ways of separating the samples.
The minimum error will give you the range of threshold values. 
***Questions:***
1. I haven't understand this '' The minimum error will give you the range of threshold values. ''
2. if i find the threshold how i can detrmine the parity of the weak classifier using min error